# why does the for-loop go through the args three times?

Tags: java, for-loop, count

I want to know why the for-loop counts through the args three times and doesn't stop after the first loop? this is my code :

```
public class test2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N = args.length;
    int[] x = new int[N];
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]); 
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < N; j++) {
            if (x[j] != x[j-1]) {
                count++;
            }
            System.out.println(count);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(N-count);
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you assume it should stop after the first loop?

Comment: Because you have 3 for loops?

Comment: I meant it should stop after it has counted all the numbers N, N is suppose to be integers in the right order f.x.{1,1,1,3,4,5,5,6}. It is suppose to print out 2 because there are two numbers that appear more than once are {1,5}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean to do this:

```
   for (int j = 1; j < N; j++) {
       if (x[j] != x[j-1]) {
           count++;
       }
       System.out.println(count);
   }
   System.out.println(N-count);
```

instead of:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < N; j++) {
        if (x[j] != x[j-1]) {
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
System.out.println(N-count);
```

Comment: It worked, but there are other things I need to change so it can count right, that's my fault, I have to change the code, but thanks :)